# Using PolyPen in Retopoflow 2.0

Tags: add-on

I have watched tutorials and demos but I cannot get the hang of the PolyPen. I end up with 2 triangles instead of a quad! :-) There's got to be a little thought trick that would make the tool work for me.

Thank you,

Sabia

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a paid addon an has support provided by the manufacturer

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer to my question by looking at a tutorial for the previous version of Retopoflow.

You need to right click on bottom edge of the existing geometry where you want to place your quad. That edge will be the top of the new quad. Then hold down Control and left drag the mouse diagonally. You'll see a temporary triangle. Click on the empty corner at the bottom of your new quad where you will place a vert. Voilà. You can make tris this way as well.

Check out the tutorials for the old version and the current version to see this in action.

Enjoy. This addon is a blockbuster!

Sabia